# .htaccess to redirect to new website structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed the website URL structure and I want to redirect my users

**The problem**

The new structure is very different, and **more strict**.

**OLD**

```
1 - https://example.com/serie-tv

2 - https://example.com/serie-tv/1845578-the-walking-dead

3 - https://example.com/serie-tv/1845578-The-Walking-Dead/seasons/1

4 - https://example.com/serie-tv/1845578-the-walking-dead/seasons/1/episodes/1
```

**NEW**

```
1 - https://example.com/browse?type=series

2 - https://example.com/titles/1845578

3 - https://example.com/titles/1845578/season/1

4 - https://example.com/titles/1845578/season/1/episode/1
```

A redirection from `https://example.com/serie-tv/1845578-the-walking-dead/seasons/1`

to
 `https://example.com/titles/1845578-the-walking-dead/season/1` will not work.

Need to redirect just to `https://example.com/titles/1845578/season/1`

For now I only managed to redirect everything under
`https://example.com/serie-tv /.....`
to
`https://example.com/browse?type=series`

with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^serie\-tv\/?(.*) "https\:\/\/example\.com\/browse?type=series" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you have multiple domains pointing to your account? If not, the checks against `HTTP_HOST` are superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight complication comes about because you have `seasons` and `episodes` (with an `s`) in the old URL structure and `season` and `episode` (no `s`) in the new URL structure, so you can't use a general solution that simply copies the URL-path.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
> ```

If you only have a single domain then these conditions are superfluous.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
> ```

For now, we can ignore these as well. cPanel will automatically inject these as required when auto-renewing your SSL certs.

> For now I only managed to redirect everything under ...

I assume you don't want to redirect "everything" since your preceding example URLs do not state this?

> ```
> RewriteRule ^serie\-tv\/?(.*) "https\:\/\/example\.com\/browse?type=series" [R=301,L]
> ```

There is unnecessary backslash escaping here that affects readability. There is no need to escape literal hyphens (`-`) and slashes in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. And in the *substitution* string (which is an "ordinary" string, not a regex), there is no need to escape the colon (`:`), slash (again) and dot. These "literal" characters carry no special meaning in the context they are used. (This is typical output having used  cPanel's redirection feature - which will often put them in the wrong place as well.)

Try something like the following instead, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/serie-tv"
RewriteRule ^serie-tv$ /browse?type=series [R=302,L]

# Redirect "/serie-tv/1845578-the-walking-dead"
RewriteRule ^serie-tv/(\d+)-[^/]+$ /titles/$1 [R=302,L]

# Redirect "/serie-tv/1845578-the-walking-dead/seasons/1"
RewriteRule ^serie-tv/(\d+)-[^/]+/seasons/(\d+)$ /titles/$1/season/$2 [R=302,L]

# Redirect "/serie-tv/1845578-the-walking-dead/seasons/1/episodes/1"
RewriteRule ^serie-tv/(\d+)-[^/]+/seasons/(\d+)/episodes/(\d+)$ /titles/$1/season/$2/episode/$3 [R=302,L]
```

`\d` is a shorthand character class for digits (the same as `[0-9]`) and `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.

`$1`, `$2` and `$3` are backreferences to the captured groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. It's more efficient to test what you can in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead of using a preceding condition that checks the `REQUEST_URI` server variable.

Note that these are currently 302 (temporary) redirects. Only change to 301 (permanent) when you have tested that they work OK - in order to avoid caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

*Aside:* The old URL structure, that includes the title maybe better from an SEO / useability perspective?

Comment: You can also tell me how to redirect `https://example.com/search?q=batman` to `https://example.com/search?query=batman` (`q` to `query` after `?`)

Comment: I see you've [asked another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245958/htaccess-redirect-with-query-string-on-new-website-structure) relating to that (and correctly so). I've moved my reply to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /serie-tv$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ browse?type=series [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /serie-tv/([0-9]*)\-([^/]*)/?(.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ titles/%1/%3 [R=301,L]
```