# .htaccess redirect with query string on new website structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed the website URL structure and I want to redirect my users.

**Need to redirect from:**

```
https://example.com/find?q=batman
```

**To**

```
https://example.com/search?query=batman
```

**where** "batman" **is the search phrase**.

The problem for me, is how to change

`q` to `query` after `?`

Something like that, it does not work

```
RewriteRule ^find?q=[^/] /search?query=[^/] [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only - this notably excludes the query string.

Instead, you need to use a `RewriteCond` directive to check the `QUERY_STRING` server variable and capture the remainder of the query string after the `q=`.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^find$ /search?query=%1 [R=302,L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*. ie. `(.*)` - the value of the `q` URL parameter and remainder of the query string.

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) only once you have confirmed that it works OK - to avoid caching issues.

Comment: This code does not work - it does not change at all, and the result is the same `https://example.com/find?q=batman` (does not redirect)

Comment: Sory, - the code just change `q` to `query` , but not change `find` to `search` . So the rezulting URL is `https://example.com/find?query=batman`

Comment: Adding an absolute path, solve the problem `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^find$ https://example.com/search?query=%1 [R=302,L]`

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I'd based my answer on [your comment to my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191674/htaccess-to-redirect-to-new-website-structure#comment99109363_56228833), where you'd stated "`/search?q=batman` to `/search?query=batman`" (no mention of `find`). I've updated my answer